# Error in cloud storage package tests - how to fix it?

Tags: bucket, cloud-storage

After creating Buckets, I get the following error in the test.

Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location", "errors": [ { "message": "We're sorry, but this service is not available in your location", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ] } } in /var/www/woowsent_new/data/www/woowsent.com/assets/libraries/google-lib/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php:368 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/woowsent_new/data/www/woowsent.com/assets/libraries/google-lib/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php(207): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException() #1 /var/www/woowsent_new/data/www/woowsent.com/assets/libraries/google-lib/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Upload/MultipartUploader.php(44): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send() #2 /var/www/woowsent_new/data/www/woowsent.com/assets/libraries/google-lib/vendor/google/cloud-storage/src/Bucket.php(295): Google\Cloud\Core\Upload\MultipartUploader->upload() #3 /var/www/woowsent_new/data/www/woowsent.com/xhr/admin_setting.php(5415): Google\Cloud\Storage\Bucket->upload() #4 /var/www/woowsent_new/data/www/woowsent.com/requests.php(141): include('...') #5 {main}

Refers to my location. Is it possible to bypass or fix it?
Or is there a problem with the location of my server?

I wanted to upload files from my site to the cloud, not to my server.